# Oracle Advanced Queue: Access a queue from another database and dequeue

Tags: plsql, queue

To keep things simple, I have a queue on Database A. I have a package and code in Database B. The code is really just a giant dequeue which dequeues the message in the queue and does stuff with the data. I know that if it was a table I would just do SELECT .. FROM tablename@databaselink. But I want to run the dequeue function and have it dequeue from the queue. Any help would be awesome.

I can do the @dblink with the message to call the message from the other DB to set my message to the one that was created for the queue but Im unsure of how to call the actual queue in the begin portion and dequeue it.

```
DECLARE

  dequeue_options     dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t;
   message_properties  dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
   message_handle      RAW(16);
   message             user.message;

BEGIN

  DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(queue_name => 'queue_name',
   dequeue_options    => dequeue_options,
   message_properties => message_properties,
   payload            => message,
   msgid              => message_handle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd create a package on the remote database to handle the dequeue, enqueue, etc operations, and grant execute on that package to the schema the local database connects as.

Then on the local db you can do:

```
package_name.dequeue_proc@remote_db (queue_name => 'QUEUE_NAME',
                                     ...);
```

If you can't do that, the following ought to work:

```
DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE@remote_db (queue_name => 'QUEUE_NAME',
                           ...);
```